# Indexes in SQL vs ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-order-by

What is the difference between using Indexes in SQL vs Using the ORDER BY clause?

Since from what I understand , the Indexes arrange the specified column(s) in an ordered manner that helps the query engine in looking through the tables quickly (and hence prevents table scan).

My question - why can't the query engine simply use the `ORDER BY` for improving performance?

Thanks !

Comment: They're two very different things. A correctly-ordered index can be used by order by so it doesn't have to work out the order each time the query is run...

Comment: Ok , you say they are 2 very different things ?

You mean -
ORDER BY - query
Index - way of storing data.

If that is true , then I think I now see why this post is quite wrong then....

Answer (score 2):

You put the tag as sql-server-2008 but the question has nothing to do with SQL server. This question will apply to all databases.
From wikipedia:

> Indexing is a technique some storage engines use for improving
>   database performance. **The many types of indexes share the common
>   property that they reduce the need to examine every entry when running
>   a query. In large databases, this can reduce query time/cost by orders
>   of magnitude.** The simplest form of index is a sorted list of values
>   that can be searched using a binary search with an adjacent reference to the location of the entry, analogous to the index in the back of a book. The same data can have multiple indexes (an employee database could be indexed by last name and hire date).

From a related thread in [StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql)

> In the SQL world, order is not an inherent property of a set of data.
>   Thus, you get no guarantees from your RDBMS that your data will come
>   back in a certain order -- or even in a consistent order -- unless you
>   query your data with an ORDER BY clause.

To answer why the indexes are necessary?

1. Note the bolded text about indexing regarding the reduction in the need to examine every entry. In the absence of an index when an **ORDER BY** is issued in SQL, every entry need to be examined which increases the number of entries.
2. **ORDER BY** is applied only when reading. A single column may be used in indexes in which case there could be several different kinds of ordering in sql query requests. It is not possible to define the indexes unless we understand how the query requests are made.
3. A lot of times indexes are added once new patterns of querying emerge so as to keep the query performant which mean index creation is driven by how you defined your **ORDER BY** in SQL.
4. Query engine which processes your SQL with/without **ORDER BY**, defines your execution plan and does not understand Storage of data. The Data retrieved from a query engine may be partly from memory if the data was in cache and partly/fully from disk. When reading from disk in the storage engine will uses the indexes to figure the quickly read data.
5. **ORDER BY** effects the performance of a query when reading. Index effects the performance of a query when doing all the Create, Read, Update and Delete operations.
6. A query engine may choose to use an index or totally ignore the index based on the data characteristics.